# Printing 0x00 to standard output

Tags: c, binary

I have a C program. Skeleton is copied below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char arr[5] = {0x01,0x02,0x03,0x00,0x04};
    printf("\n%d \n",strlen(arr));
    printf("%s", arr);
    return 0;
}
```

The value 0x00 in the char array is being treated as end of input ( NULL ) as expected and the output is
3
output till 0x03

However my requirement is to print the entire array to the standard output. Can anyone let me know how i can go about it?

Thanks

Comment: Use for loop to access each element in array and print as int

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to print the values as integers? Since your character array does not really correspond to a printable string.

Comment: Was the `[c++]` tag a mistake? The auto-completion is too eager? This doesn't look like C++ code to me...

Comment: `printf()` works with **strings**. The char `'\0'`, though part of strings, is not considered in many situations (like when printing). You have to print using functions NOT designed for strings.

Comment: How would I get length for this character array to loop through it?

Comment: The number of elements of an **array** can always be calculated as `sizeof array / sizeof *array`.

Answer (score 3):

There are various methods: you could use [putchar](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putchar) in a loop, for example, or you could just use [fwrite](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fwrite):

```
fwrite(arr, 1, sizeof(arr), stdout);
```